# MATLAB - Spectrogram function

Tags: matlab, audio

I've a wav sound file and made a spectrogram of it. My goal is to show how much frequency range a sound can cover. But I honestly do not know what the spectrogram shows and tells me.

Here's what I've got

```
load handel; % 'handel' is a MAT-file which is shipped with MATLAB as an example
x = y/100; % Decrease volume
player = audioplayer(x, Fs);
play(player,[1 (get(player, 'SampleRate')*10)]);
spectrogram(x);
```

Spectrogram(x) prints this, when x=y/100:
[image]

Spectrogram(x) prints this, when x=y/1:
[image]

My analysis:
Based on my little knowledge, I assume that the colors have something to do with the volume of the sound. The green color shows how high the volume is playing, so the more dense green lines you get, the louder the music plays. And the fewer green lines there are, the lower the music plays.

- Am I wrong?

---

Anyone that can tell me what the spectrogram function does and shows? What does the yellow and green color mean?

Comment: In addition to Jim Lewis' answer, the chirp examples in the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/spectrogram.html) are very illustrative. Also, for the `handel` clip you may want to experiment with the optional second input of `spectrogram` to increase time resolution, for example `spectrogram(x, 1e3)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to gloss over a lot of the fine details, but the basic idea is that any complicated waveform (like an audio recording) can be thought of as a combination of simpler waveforms (for example, pure sine waves at various frequencies) whose intensities vary over time.  A sound that's lower in pitch (for example, a bass, or the low notes on a piano) would have most of the power in the low frequencies, while the sound of a piccolo or a snare drum hit would have a lot of power in the higher frequencies.

A spectrogram is a way of showing how the frequency content in the signal varies over time.  In your example, time seems to increasing up the Y axis, while the frequency is displayed on the X axis, with higher frequencies to the right.   At any given time and frequency, the color represents the amount of power at that frequency at that time, as shown in the color bar on the right side of the plot.

Comment: Thanks alot for the good explanation :-)
So in short; I can use it to show how the frequency content of the signal varies over time? So in relation to the blue or purple color, they will then be a more higher frequency? To achieve that, I guess I just have to turn up the frequency / volume of the audio single?